# Java String character analysis

Tags: java, string, drjava

I'm writing a simple program in dr java to read a string and then compare the first and last characters. I tried to put some validation into it, but I'm having trouble with the syntax:

```
1 error found:
File: /Users/Luke/Documents/University/Programming/Lab/Week 10/wordAnalysis.java  [line: 11]
Error: /Users/Luke/Documents/University/Programming/Lab/Week 10/wordAnalysis.java:11: incomparable types: char and java.lang.String
```

Error is about the if statement checking for spaces within the while loop:

```
import java.util.*;
public class wordAnalysis {
public static void main(String [] args) {
String word;
int charactercount;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please type a word without spaces, (done to stop) ");
word = sc.next();

while (charactercount <=  word.length()) {
  if (word.charAt(charactercount) == " "){
    System.out.println("your word cannot contain spaces please try again.");
    wordAnalysis.main(args);
  }
}


if (word == "done"){
  System.exit(0);
}
if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
  System.out.print("the words first and last letter are the same!");
}
else {
  System.out.println("the words first and last letters dont match, try again...");
}

wordAnalysis.main(args);
```

}
}

Comment: Hint: "string" is made of 'c' 'h' 'a' 'r' 's'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (word.charAt(charactercount) == " "){
```

is using `==` to compare 2 different things, left is a char, and right is a String.  So they can't be equal even if they're both spaces.  The char version of a space looks like `' '`.

There's other problems which will stop that code from working, but that's the one you're asking about at the moment.